# Boolean difference produces incorrect result

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I'm carving letters on a cylinder with the Boolean difference operator.
This worked well for a while, but suddenly a strange result became to occur:
[image]
[image]

As you can see, a part of the letter made a pit in the cylinder (as intended), while outside part produced "walls" around the letter edge.

I already checked for [broken normals](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50611/boolean-modifiers-not-working-normally/50632) and [duplicate vertices](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43875/why-wont-text-boolean-correctly-after-the-second-boolean-operation).

Also, I can not see mesh geometry when I switch to wireframe shading (not sure if it's releated):
[image]

The file itself can be downloaded from here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8QGeF3SuAgTRXNyZ2xsZVV4Tk0

What do I need to fix to make this operation work correctly?

Comment: Not sure if you use Ngons here. Try to triangulate your meshes before you do boolean operations. Sometimes it also helps to give the objecs a slight offset when the first try doesn't work. But you will nearly always end in a result where you have to fix something. That's the nature of boolean :)

Comment: Make sure you apply the scale and rotation of the objects. In Object Mode select an object and press CTRL + "A" and select "Rotation and Scale" from the drop down menu.

Comment: @Dontwalk Thanks, that fixed it! Could you please convert your comment to an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you apply the scale and rotation of the objects. In Object Mode select an object and press CTRL + "A" and select "Rotation and Scale" from the drop down menu.